# Not finding strongly typed Resources when using Global Resources

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, resources, globalization

I can't believe I'm asking this question, since this seems to be a very easy to accomplish, but... How do I access global resources considering culture and uiculture?

I created two files under the App_GlobalResources folder:

- Unit.en-US.resx
- Unit.pt-BR.resx

And created an entry with the key value of SearchTitle and text "Bla bla bla".

In the web.config file I added:

```
<globalization uiCulture="auto:en" culture="auto:en-US" />
```

But now I don't know how to access the resource file. I tried (in Unit.aspx.cs):

```
string s = Resources.Unit.SearchTitle
```

But ***Resources*** is not recognized or doesn't exists.

Also tried:

```
<label><%$ Resources:Unit, SearchTitle %></label>
```

And, finally, also tried to set a custom tool for the resource file, but I wasn't sure what do afterwards:

```
PublicResXFileCodeGenerator
```

I've never worked with resources before, and my goal is to use them to translate aspx pages to different languages depending on the user's Culture.

I'm using VS 2012 and .NET 4.0.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below, just to figure out if your project is setup correctly:

```
GetGlobalResourceObject("Unit", "SearchTitle")
```

What type of app is it? I normally don't need to set a custom tool or build action.